# Error handling with loops in node.js is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

So I am trying to understand how should I handle error with loops.
I have a table through which I loop and do something, if I get an error while looping through the table I want to handle that error. If I don't get and error while looping but I get an error before or after the loop I want to handle that error in a different way.

```
try#1{

for(let i=0;i<x;i++}{
  let result  = do something
  
  try#2{
      send result
  }catch#2(e){
       context#1.res={
                  status:e.response.status,
                  body: {
                       message : e.response.statusText,
                       detail:e.response.data
                   },
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
                   }
       };
}
context#2.res={
       status:e.response.status,
       body: {
            message : e.response.statusText,
            detail:e.response.data
            },
            headers: {
              'Content-Type':  'application/json'
           }
        };
}
catch#1(e){
context#3.res={
         status:e.response.status,
         body: {
            message : e.response.statusText,
            detail:e.response.data
              },
         headers: {
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
             }
       };

}
```

try #1 and catch #1 are outside the loop and try #2 and catch #2 are inside the loop.
Now I want that if an error occurs during the loop iteration try#2 and catch#2 should handle it. But if and error occurs before or after the loop starts/finishes try #1 and catch #1 should handle it.
But what actually is happening is even if an error is coming inside loop, catch #2 is not stopping the program and handling the error instead context#2 is running and showing result.

How should I handle errors inside loop?